# Why does rsyslog replace tabs with #011?

Tags: nginx, centos, rsyslog

I am using rsyslog to collect nginx logs. All looks good except the replacing usual tabs with '#011' text.

Nginx log format defined with '\t' delimiter.

Example of corrupted output:

```
217.118.93.88#0111473674833.412#0114418687#011...
```

How it should look:

```
217.118.93.88    1473674833.412    4418687    ...
```

Why it is happens and how to disable such replacing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The "quick dirty" fix is to disable escaping special characters.

Add in rsyslog.conf

```
$EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive off
```

Despite it is acceptable solution for my case it could be harmful for more complex situations.